# Inno Setup, WizardImageFile is stretched even for 100% DPI

Tags: inno-setup

Inno Setup 6.2.0, Windows 10 21H1

The Wizard image's actual size for 100% DPI is actually bigger than the requested size in manual (164x314). I created empty project with the default image and compared the sizes. The original image was taken from the resources file from [InnoSetup GitHub](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Projects/Images2.res).

Image stretched in the wizard:

[image]

Original image

[image]

As you can see, the image in the Wizard is stretched. I know about `WizardImageStretch=no` option, but it is not the case. The [InnoSetup manual](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardimagefile) says that for 100% DPI the image should be 164x314 pixels, but for some reason this size is valid. Is this a bug in InnoSetup which makes the image container bigger than it should be or the incorrect values in the manual?

Same problem occurs if I use `WizardImageFile` with my custom images which have sizes according to the manual. The DPI on my PC is certainly [set to 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIpJR.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me on Windows 8.1 (measured using Gimp).

1. Are you sure the setup is not affected by any 3rd party tools like ISSkin, VCL Styles or Graphical Installer for Inno Setup?
2. Do you realize since Inno 6 there is a new **WizardStyle=modern** Setup directive?

When this directive is effective the WizardForm is stretched (it is slightly larger, not zoomed!) and the image is also stretched appropriately.

Picture of your installer looks bigger then mine, **try to grab the corner of the window and drag it to make the window smaller (as small as possible).**
That is 100% zoom, no stretching and the image dimensions should be correct.

[image: Dimensions on Win 8.1]

Comment: You're right. Found out that `WizardStyle=modern` directive stretches the default window size up to 120%: https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Projects/Compile.pas#L8666

Looks like that the `WizardImageFile` manual page should be updated with the new image sizes.